# Centered elements in div appear to be off center

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a website, which for testing reasons I have called `yeet.io`.

I'm currently trying to center an `input` and `h1` inside of a `div` both vertically and horizontally, but for some reason, the elements always appear offsetted somehow.

Why is this? I want the elements to be centered in the middle like any regular "io game". I have some jQuery that makes the elements fade in, could this be the problem? I am stumped.

```js
$(".yeet").hide();
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".yeet").show(2000);
  $(".nickname").show(2000);
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.yeet {
  font-family: "Schoolbell", cursive;
  font-size: 75px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.nickname {
  font-family: "Schoolbell", cursive;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Schoolbell" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="yeet">yeet.io</h1>
    <input class="nickname" placeholder="nickname" , autofocus="autofocus">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: When you say you are trying to center the two elements, **how** exactly do you want them to be centered? The `<input>` on top of the `<h1>`, or the `<input>` to the right of `<h1>`? Centering both elements both horizontally and vertically would mean that they sit on top of each other, which is probably not intentional.

Comment: By using `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;` you are effectively creating a `<table>`. I suspect you don't want to do this.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I want the `<input>` to be below the `<h1>`

Comment: " I have some jQuery that makes the elements fade in, could this be the problem?" So take the jQuery out. Eliminating possibilities and simplifying your problem with help you arrive at the solution for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently making use of a `table`, by setting `display: table` on `.container`, and `display: table-cell` on `.yeet`.

This is probably unintentional, and in fact, simply removing these two declarations automatically produces your desired result -- you don't have to change the HTML at all, or create any new CSS rules.

```js
$(".yeet").hide();
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".yeet").show(2000);
  $(".nickname").show(2000);
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.yeet {
  font-family: "Schoolbell", cursive;
  font-size: 75px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.nickname {
  font-family: "Schoolbell", cursive;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Schoolbell" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="yeet">yeet.io</h1>
    <input class="nickname" placeholder="nickname" , autofocus="autofocus">
  </div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap each element in their own fake table-row

```js
$(".yeet").hide();
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".yeet").show(2000);
  $(".nickname").show(2000);
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.yeet {
  font-family: "Schoolbell", cursive;
  font-size: 75px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.nickname {
  font-family: "Schoolbell", cursive;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.row{
  display:table-row;
 }
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Schoolbell" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h1 class="yeet">yeet.io</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <input class="nickname" placeholder="nickname" , autofocus="autofocus">
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".yeet").hide();
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".yeet").show(2000);
  $(".nickname").show(2000);
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.yeet {
  font-family: "Schoolbell", cursive;
  font-size: 75px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nickname {
  font-family: "Schoolbell", cursive;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Schoolbell" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="yeet">yeet.io</h1>
    <input class="nickname" placeholder="nickname" , autofocus="autofocus">
  </div>
</body>
```